# Activate a button of a macro from a macro in another book

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that is updated by date, and a book that has another table that manages to link with the date of the macro of the other book.

I cannot activate the update button. It does not update itself if I do not give it the ok manually.

I need to activate the button from the other macro in another book so that it is updated without the need to press it manually.

```vb
Sub ancla1()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

 Windows("Plantilla PyG Semanal.xlsm").Activate
  Sheets("Hoja1").Select
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Informe de PyG.xlsm").Activate
     Sheets("Nivel 1").Select
    Range("A4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
         Windows("Plantilla PyG Semanal.xlsm").Activate
          Sheets("Hoja1").Select
         Windows("Informe de PyG.xlsm").Activate
          Sheets("Nivel 1").Select
          Application.Run "'Informe de PyG.xlsm'!cambiarCorte"

End Sub
```

Comment: `cambiarCorte` should be in a standard module. If it is not you can create a one-liner in a **standard module**, e.g. if the cambiarCorte is in `Sheet1` (code name (the name not in parentheses)), you could use: `Sub RunCambiarCorte: Sheet1.cambiarCorte: End Sub`. Then you could do `Application.Run "'Informe de PyG.xlsm'!RunCambiarCorte"` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the workbook with `workbooks.open ("workbookdirectory")`, then close workbook after.

```
Application.Run "'SomeWorkbookName.xlsm'!NameOfMacro"
```